# display keyboard with button list on the top

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

I hope to push keyboard with button list on the top of the keyboard.
Please refer to the image

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a toolbar. Here is an example I used for an action sheet - you can make the modifications for the keyboard easily:

```
  //DEFINING TOOL BAR 
UIToolbar * keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
keyboardToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[keyboardToolbar sizeToFit];    
NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[barItems addObject:flexSpace];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard:)];
[barItems addObject:doneBtn];
[keyboardToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
[keyboard addSubview:keyboardToolbar];
```

You can obviously add more items to the UIToolBar for "Next", "Previous", etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Here is a link to a [keyboard controls project](https://github.com/SimonBS/BSKeyboardControls) on github.